# Добавление элементов в StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь динамически добавлять элементы в StackPanel.

```
<StackPanel Name="Panel1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" Margin="0,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto">
</StackPanel>
```

Вот класс, где пытаюсь добавить:

```
public class DynamicCreator 
{
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    public void TextBoxCreator(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            main.Panel1.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Content = "Test"
            });
        }

        main.UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

Но элементы не появляются. Что делать? Где ошибка?

Comment: ...вам самому нравится такой код?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper , я задаю тут вопрос, потому что нуждаюсь в помощи, если вам не нравится мой код, то, пожалуйста, не минусуйте, а напишите где ошибка и как ее исправить. Я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: с удовольствием вам помогу если вы напишите, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Я хочу добавлять n-нное количество `Label` в элемент `StackPanel` по нажатию кнопки. Для этого я сделал отдельный класс, где есть метод `TextBoxCreator`,  который с помощью цикла должен добавлять эти элементы. Если делать тоже самое из `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, то все работает, но я хочу понять, как добавлять элементы в MainWindow из другого класса.

Comment: смотрите вы идете совсем не тем путем, работайте с данными а не с элементами управления. Исходя из вашего описания вы просто хотите отобразить некоторую коллекцию данных, которая может изменяться, в частности - при нажатии на кнопку добавляться элементы. Есть стандартное решение - `ObservableCollection`, коллекция которая сообщает о своем изменении.

Comment: написать пример не составит труда, но подобного материала в интернете хватает с избытком, [например](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection). Если не все будет получаться - спрашивайте

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, мне надо динамически добавлять пустые `TextBox 'ы`, откуда потом я буду считывать введенные данные. `Label` я пытался добавить для теста. В моем случае будет возможно использовать `ObservableCollection` для добавления `TextBox` или `ObservableCollection` только для работы с данными?

Comment: конечно, вы просто замените в xaml `Label` на `TextBox`

Comment: получилось разобраться с вопросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храни свои `Label` где-то в `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Label> myLabels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Label>();
```

Делай привязку:

```
<ItemsControl Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding myLabels}"></ItemsControl>
```

Добавляй в коде нужные тебе `Label`:

```
myLabels.Add(...);
```

P.S: не забудь про `DataContext`: `DataContext = this`.

Comment: интересно по какой причине ваш ответ получил минус

Comment: @FoggyFinder, кому-то, наверное, не понравился ответ.

Comment: похоже, я уже не в первый раз замечаю когда хорошие ответы получают `-` без видимых причин и без комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что вы добавляете не в то окно. Не создавайте новый экземпляр MainWindow, возьмите существующий.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не совсем понял. Как взять существующий экземпляр?

Comment: @Nikita, а откуда вы метод этот вызываете? Нельзя оттуда передать ссылку на окно (this)?

Comment: @Nikita: Ну это у вас как программиста нужно спросить, где в вашей программе можно раздобыть ссылку на главное окно.